# How can I show a viewbag as html?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

OK, quite new to ASP.Net MVC, so I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but how do I go about showing the values of a ViewBag as HTML. For Example, if ViewBag.SomeMessage contains the following text:

`<h3>Test</h3><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>TEST</p>`

How would I go about actually having the page render that as normal HTML? Or is there a much easier way of achieving this that I'm totally missing?

Cheers!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Everyone is correct in the use of `@Html.Raw()` but I want to point out to be careful with this, as it can make your site susceptible to XSS vulnerabilities.

I would combine the `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SomeMessage)` with [Microsoft's Anti-XSS Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814) to make sure you do not introduce any vulnerabilities from this.

**Edit:**
The advantage of the Anti-XSS library (if you haven't looked at it) is it has a whitelist of approved markups (such as `<b>`, `<h3>`, etc..) so that only approved markups will be un-encoded.

**Edit2:**
[Here's an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/09/01/html-sanitization-in-anti-xss-library.aspx) of how this is done.

Comment: shameless self promotion on what xss is and using anti-xss, plus other hack proofing stuff:  http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/DEV333

Comment: As far as the Anti-XSS library is concerned, are you saying there is a way to implement it that will change the behavior of Html.Raw to do what you outlined, or are you stating to use it with Html.Raw in order to be safe?

Answer (score 19):

You would use the `Raw` method:

```
 @Html.Raw(ViewBag.SomeMessage)
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you can do something like this:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SomeMessage)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SomeHtmlProperty)
```

This being said, here's my disclaimer: DON'T USE ViewBag. Use strongly typed views and view models. ViewBag/ViewData is like cancer for an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Why?  Please explain.  Why is ViewBag "like cancer"?

Answer (score 3):

put data to ViewBag as a HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again.

```
ViewBag.myBag = MvcHtmlString.Create(myCode ?? string.Empty);
```

then use

```
@ViewBag.myBag
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring(VS.100).aspx) for MvcHtmlString.